# How to solve unwanted bookmarks dependency between different parts (or section) in Book

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, bookmarks

Compiling a book (i.e. `\documentclass{book}`) I have a problem with the bookmarks.

Here there is the structure I would like to obtain (the large spaces denotes a visual dependency in the bookmark from the objects above):

```
Contents
Preface
1. Introduction
Part 1
    2. Title
Part 2
    3. Title
```

while this is what I obtain:

```
Contents
    Preface
    1. Introduction
Part 1
    2. Title
Part 2
    3. Title
```

This is the result of the following piece of code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
%
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
%
\newcommand{\mychapter}[2]{
    \setcounter{chapter}{#1}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \chapter*{#2}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}
}
%
%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\maketitle

\pagenumbering{roman}

\setcounter{page}{0}

\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Contents}

\pagestyle{plain}

%%%%%%%%%%%%
\mychapter{0}{Preface}

\mainmatter


%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Introduction}

%%%%%%%%
\part{Title}

\chapter{Title}


%%%%%%%%
\part{Title}

\chapter{Title}

\end{document}
```

Few points concerning this piece of code:

1. Of course, if we delete the string `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Contents}` all the problems are fixed, in the sense that both the preface and the chapter "1. introduction" are at the same bookmark level of "Part 1" and "Part 2". Still, in this way I don't get the contents in the bookmarks, and I would like to have them there.
2. I included the option `hypertexnames=false` because this was the solution I found here to a problem I had with hyperref.
3. The command `\newcommand{\mychapter}[2]{... etc...}` is again a solution I found here for what I wanted to get.

Any feedback concerning this issue is most welcome.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bookmark package to reset levels. And you should consider to use a better class so that you don't have to do this \mychapter-stuff:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
%
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
%


\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\maketitle

\frontmatter
\hypertarget{toc}{}
\bookmark[dest=toc]{\contentsname}
\tableofcontents

\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
\addchap{Preface}

\mainmatter

\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
\chapter{Introduction}

\part{Title}

\chapter{Title}

\part{Title}

\chapter{Title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works supersmoothly (indeed, you are right, but for now I would like to stick to `book`out of pure ignorance and lack of time). Just one last question: in this way I got the line `Contents` both in the TOC and in the bookmarks. *How can I get rid of that line in the TOC?*

Comment: You don't get contents in the toc with my example -- I made quite sure to remove it as I think it is silly to mention the toc in the toc.

Comment: Indeed, sorry & thanks a lot: It works just great!

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but I got a minor problem: the bookmark associated to `Contents` doesn't point to the TOC, but to the page just *before* the TOC. Could this be fixed?

Comment: Not in my example ...

Comment: Indeed, you are right. Now I am not just sorry, but also ashamed. Thanks a lot!